# why the copy constructor is called twice when the object is contained in another object in c++?

Tags: c++

```
//V4.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class V3 {
private:
    double x, y, z;
public:
    V3(double a, double b, double c): x(a), y(b), z(c) {
        cout << "V3(double, double, double)" << endl; 
    }
    V3(const V3 &a): x(a.x), y(a.y), z(a.z) {
        cout << "V3(const V3 &)" << endl;
    }
};
class V4 {
private:
    V3 xyz;
    double time;
public:
    V4(V3 a, double t): xyz(a), time(t) {
        cout << "V4(V3, double)" << endl;
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    V3 xyz(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    double t(4.0);
    V4 xyzt(xyz, t);

    return 0;
}
```

the class V4 contains another class V3, and the object of V4 is initialized by an exist object of V3, so the V4's constructor will call V3's copy constructor, and I think the copy constructor will be called once, but the result shows it's called tiwce, why is it?

compile the code:

```
g++ V4.cpp -o V4 -Wall
```

and run:

```
./V4
```

and the result:

```
V3(double, double, double)
V3(const V3 &)
V3(const V3 &)
V4(V3, double)
```

so look the result, why the V3 copy constructor is called twice?
my OS is Lubuntu16.04,and g++ is 5.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're taking `V3 a` by value in `V4`'s constructor, resulting in an additional unnecessary copy. You should take it by `const&`:

```
class V4 {
private:
    V3 xyz;
    double time;
public:
    V4(const V3& a, double t): xyz(a), time(t) {
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^
        cout << "V4(V3, double)" << endl;
    }
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DBRheZY6EZ5XSqB4)

Comment: I have just try you code, and the copy constructor was called once, thank you!

Comment: @fagdih: you're welcome. Don't forget to "mark my answer as accepted" by clicking the green tick next to the vote buttons if it solved your problem.

Comment: @fagdih: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work